# if let with OR condition

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Is it possible to use an "OR" condition using Swift's `if let`?

Something like (for a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` dictionary):

```
if let value = dictionary["test"] as? String or as? Int {
       println("WIN!")
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `as? AnyObject`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would make no sense, how would you be able to tell whether value is an Int or a String when you only have one if statement? You can however do something like this:

```
let dictionary : [String : Any] = ["test" : "hi", "hello" : 4]


if let value = dictionary["test"] where value is Int || value is String {
    print(value)
}
```

(Tested in Swift 2.0)

You can also do this if you need to do different things depending on the types:

```
if let value = dictionary["test"] {
    if let value = value as? Int {
        print("Integer!")
    } else if let value = value as? String {
        print("String!")
    } else {
        print("Something else")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately to my knowledge you cannot. You will have to use two separate if statements.

```
if let value = dictionary["test"] as? String {
   doMethod()
} else if let value = dictionary["test"] as? Int {
   doMethod()
}
```

There are multiple ways of getting around this problem. This is just one of them.
Please refer to the Apple documentation on [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) for more information on this special type of if statement. This is with using Swift 1.2