# Multiple if let and OR condition in swift

Tags: swift

I've three optional values. These values are read from JSON. First I want to guard these values with if let then I want to check the values themselves.

I want to check if one of these value is present and then do something.

I'm aware that multiple if lets in one statement are && conditions. How do I make it || condition with less code?

JSON:

```
{value1="", value2="", value3="Some value"}

struct Profile: Decodable
    let value1: String?
    let value3: String?
    let value3: String?
}
```

Following is a pseudo code:

```
if let value1 = profile.value1 || let value2 = profile.value2 || let value3 = profile.value3 {
    // One of these value is present
    if value1 != "null" {
        // do something
    } else if value2 != "null" {
        // do something
    } else if value3 != "null" {
        // do something
    } else {
        // No value present
    }
} else {
    // None of these values is present
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if let with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670295/if-let-with-or-condition)

Comment: Not entirely. It seems I'm ending up with a nested multiple and complex if else. I was wondering if there is simpler solution.

Comment: How would you use `value2` and `value3` within the outher `then` branch? Do you need them? If not, a simple `!= nil` for those two would suffice.

Comment: I'll check and use any value if it's present.

Comment: You don't need the OR outer if, in that case.

Comment: Values are decoded from JSON what if the optional values are corrupted after json decode, I need to guard them first otherwise it will crash? Am I missing something? Please elaborate with code if possible.

Comment: I like these pure Swift language questions, especially when dealing with thorny corner cases like nil. Why the downvote?

Comment: @P2000 if you check the edit history, the question was very vague, and the accepted answer not only doesn't really answer what the question is asking (there's no OR logic in that answer), but it's also pretty basic, so I would say that OP didn't do a good job asking, even after the edits.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, fair, it took me a few reads to figure out what the question was, even in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let value1 = profile.value1, value1 != “” {}
else if value2 = profile.value2, value2 != “” {}
else if value3 = profile.value3, value3 != “” {}
```

here `,` acts like &&

Pay attention: 
For Swift 2 replace `,` with `where`

Comment: @Raymond Good luck

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check that at least one is not `nil`, you can just compare to `nil`.

```
if value1 != nil || value2 != nil || value3 != nil {
    // One of these values is present
} else {
    // None of these values is present
}
```

If you want to use the value that isn't `nil`, then it depends on the types of the variables. If they are all the same type you can use `nil coalescing` like this

```
if let value = value1 ?? value2 ?? value3 {
    // One of these values is present
} else {
    // None of these values is present
}
```

This will bind `value` to the first one of those variables that isn't `nil`, but it will only work if they are the same type or if they conform to a shared protocol (you might have to cast them in this case). Now you will be able to use `value` as that shared class/protocol.

If they are different types, you could cast the value to `Any`, but that's not super useful since you'd have to check its type and act accordingly, instead I would use an `if let` for each variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use OR condition with if let statement. alternatively you can try following options.

First,

```
      if let _ = value1 {
            //One is present
        } else if let  _ = value2 {
            //One is present
        } else if let  _ = value3 {
            //One is present
        }
```

Second,

```
if let value = value1 ?? value2 ?? value3 {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: Very nice `if let value = value1 ?? value2 ?? value3` indeed works: value gets the first non-nil. But why?

Comment: @P2000 this is so called [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if-let`, try checking for `nil` value in the variables

```
if value1 != nil || value2 != nil || value3 != nil {
    // One of these value is present
} else {
    // None of these values is present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a `switch` statmenent with a tuple made up of the variables

```
switch (value1, value2, value3) {
case let (.some(value1), _, _):
    ...
case let (_ , .some(value2), _):
    ...
case let (_ ,_ , .some(value3)):
    ...
default: 
print("all nil")    
}
```

`.some` is used to unwrap the variable.

Comment: Mind-blowing coding skills.